# Angular.js directive where element is moved to another DOM location

Tags: angularjs, semantic-ui, angular-directive

I've created a directive for a [Semantic UI modal](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html).

By default the Modal will move the modal DOM element from its initial location (inside the directive) to the `<body>`. A reduced example:

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- <core-modal> -->
    <div class="ng-isolate-scope">
      <div class="ui modal">
        <p>Here is my modal content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```js
$element.find('.ui.modal').modal();
```

Becomes:

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- <core-modal> -->
    <div class="ng-isolate-scope"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="ui dimmer">
    <div class="ui modal">
      <p>Here is my modal content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The `core-modal` directive is no longer able to access the modal $element as the DOM element is no longer contained within the directive element. For example, to close the modal via:

```js
$element.find('.ui.modal').modal('hide');
```

There doesn't appear to be any way in Semantic UI to declaratively close the modal via the template.

How is this situation normally handled in Angular.js? Could I apply the `.modal()` call to trigger the DOM movement before the directive is compiled, then compile in the new location?

Comment: Why can't you put the modal in body yourself instead of inline with content?

Comment: This may be helpful http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2806-creating-a-simple-modal-system-in-angularjs.htm Think the main thing that would help there is if you have a modal service/manager that keeps track of any open modals then you can use that to find them regardless of where they are in the DOM

Comment: It's not clear how you use your directive to get the modal content. And in your example, we can't even see where the directive is being used in markup.

Comment: @inorganik - was trying to keep the example simple, this is demonstrating the resulting HTML once then directive is compiled. My question relates to the Angular way to track DOM elements being moved, rather than modal specifically.

Comment: The angular way is not to track DOM from script but use transclusion and directives in the markup. That's why it's important to see your directive in the markup and code for your directive.